# Deriving hyperparameter updates in Online Interactive Collaborative Filtering

Tags: statistics, optimization, machine-learning, bayesian-network

I've been going through "[Online Interactive Collaborative Filtering Using Multi-Armed Bandit with Dependent Arms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03058.pdf)" by Wang et al. and am unable to understand how the update equations for the hyperparameters (section 4.3, equation set (23)) were derived. I'd deeply appreciate it if anyone could provide a full or partial derivation of the updates. Any general suggestions regarding how to proceed with the derivation would also be appreciated.

ICTR Graphical Model

[image]

The variables are sampled as below

$$\mathbb{p}_m|\lambda \sim \text{Dirichlet}(\lambda)$$

$$\sigma^2_n|\alpha,\beta \sim \text{Inverse-Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$$

$$\mathbb{q}_n |\mu_{\mathbb{q}}, \Sigma_{\mathbb{q}}, \sigma_n^2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{\mathbb{q}}, \sigma_n^2\Sigma_{\mathbb{q}})$$

$$\mathbb{\Phi}_k |\eta \sim \text{Dirichlet}(\eta)$$

$$z_{m,t} | \mathbb{p}_m \sim \text{Multinomial}(\mathbb{p}_m)$$

$$x_{m,t} | \mathbb{\Phi}_k \sim \text{Multinomial}(\mathbb{\Phi}_k) $$

$$y_{m,t} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbb{p}_m^T\mathbb{q}_n, \sigma_n^2)$$

And the update equations are below

[image: Update equations for hyper-parameters]